# Getting Null while reading my appsettings in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, appsettings

**Here is my appsettings**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
    <add key="K1" value="Debendra Dash"/>
  </appSettings>
```

**Here is how i am trying to read in my controller:**

```
string x = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["K1"];
```

And am getting null always.
Here is my web.config.

[image]

Comment: make sure you include web.config in the project.

Comment: yes as you can see web config is in the project only.

Comment: right click in the file and click include in project

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct. 
Try a couple of things

1. See if you're editing the correct Web.config.
2. Try using WebConfigurationManager instead of ConfigurationManager